# Привести ссылку типа "http://имяхоста/директория/файл" к полному пути на сервере

Tags: php, wordpress, filesize

Заполняется форма с `input type="file"`.

Стоит задача чтобы в `input type="hidden"` записывался еще и размер файла.

Для использования функции PHP `filesize()` нужен путь к файлу от корня на стороне сервера `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, а `input type="file"` дает путь `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

Как изящно ссылку `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']/dir/file.ext` привести к `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/dir/file.ext` ?

P.S. Использую Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так решил данную задачу

```
$link = (ссылка в формате $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']/dir/file.ext)
$pserv = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$pdoc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$real_path = str_replace($pserv, $pdoc, $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Хранить ссылку в виде `/dir/file.ext`, а в зависимости от назначения подставлять либо `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, либо `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`